# Android Studio won't display Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Honestly it is giving me this error for almost anything I try to do that isn't adding simple buttons or text. I have tried everything I could think of and find on the interwebs. My API is set to the right API (8). I have updated everything I could in SDK Manager. This is the error:

Oh I cut off the beginning of the error. It says:

**Failed to configure parser for:**

[image: error]

(Cannot post images without 10 rep)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think **"Android Studio won't display Drawer Layout"** means the Palette didn't display your `DrawerLayout` instantly. Actually, it's a normal behavior. After all, the Palette only displays static monolayer views while the `DrawerLayout` is a complicated `ViewGroup` and it has multilayers: the drawer and the content. Meanwhile, `DrawerLayout` is a dynamic `View` whose effects only could be seen on a device or a simulator. So, feel free to run your Activity which loads this layout, and you will see the effect of your layout which contains your `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're probably using a lower minSdkVersion. 
You can try set the minSdkVersion to 17 or higher(in the build.gradle)

```
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 21
```